# OAuth сгенерировать сигнатуру запросса

Tags: oauth, android, хеширование

Как правильно сгенерировать сигнатуру?

Генерирую так, но сервер отвечает, что сигнатура не правильная

```
String toHash = URLEncoder.encode("POST&https://" + url + "&oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=" + key + "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp + "&oauth_nonce=" + timeStamp);

String hash = computeHmac(toHash, secret);
```

...

```
public String computeHmac(String baseString, String key)
    {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(digest));
    }
```

Comment: Что это за сервис? Twitter?

Comment: нет. общий случай сервиса, построенного на OAuth.